# Замена символов в textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017, textbox, replace

работаю на WPF. И появилась идея сделать нечто вроде программы шифрования...Делаю чисто для себя, чтобы поднять свои навыки в WPF. У меня имееются два textbox-а:

1)Вводим пароль
2)Выводит зашифрованыый

Я хочу заменять символ 'A' например на символ 'Z'.Знаю такую функцию как 'Replace', но проблема заключается в том, что я не знаю как выводить например из одного textbox в другой...То есть пользователь должен писать в textbox1 нажать на кнопку и зашифрованный пароль должен появиться в textbox2.

Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать...[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто запишите результат в свойство `Text`

Comment: должно быть что-то вроде textbox2.Text =textbox1.Text.Replace('A','Z'); - у вас это не работает?

Comment: У вас должен быть обработчик нажатия на кнопку `btnEncrypt_Click`, в котором вы присвоите значение `textBox2.Text`

Answer (score 1):

```
void Encrypt() {
    string fromUser = textbox1.Text
    fromUser = fromUser.Replace('Z', 'A');
    /*Все замены далее*/
    textbox2.Text = toUser;
}
```

Здесь мы сделали метод, который создаёт 2 переменных: 1 с значением от пользователя и 2 с выводными данными. Ну а далее, я думаю, суть ясна.

Comment: Извеняюсь, не обратил внимание на метку wpf. Но суть по-моему тут сильно не измениться. Кто знает отличия данного кода для winforms и wpf прошу правки.

Comment: это все можно было одной строкой написать

Comment: Честно для меня если человек спрашивает не самый сложный вопрос(относительно) то ему лучше розложить по полочкам а не читабильнее написать в ущерб пониманию

Comment: В данном случае читабельнее присвоение значения свойству сразу, не используя две лишние переменные

Comment: Ну с этим согласен

Answer (score 0):

В самом простом варианте (без использования MVVM) по вашему описанию необходимо сделать следующее:

1. повесить обработчик нажатия на кнопку
2. Получить содержимое первого TextBox
3. Произвести необходимые операции с текстом
4. Поместить результат во второй TextBox

Если это что то простой в виде недолгих операций по шифрованию пароля - можно и без кнопки обойтись (на ваше усмотрение).

Ниже приведен необходимый пример. 
При вводе и нажатии на кнопку будет вызываться асинхронный метод EncryptAsync в который передается строковое значение из txtInput. обработанное значение как результат будет присвоено содержимому в txtResult. Если отметить CheckBox, находящийся под кнопкой, шифрование будет выполняться по мере ввода текста в txtInput без нажатия на кнопку.

Пожалуйста создайте новый проект WPF с названием WpfApplication1 и скопируйте этот код:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <!-- Определяем строки и столбцы -->
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- TextBox для ввода + обработчик ввода текста txtInput_TextChanged -->
        <TextBox Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="0" Name="txtInput" Height="25" Margin="10" TextChanged="txtInput_TextChanged"/>
        <!-- TextBox для вывода результата -->
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Name="txtResult" Height="25" Margin="10"/>
        <!-- Кнопка для выполнения операции + обработчик нажатия на кнопку btnEncrypt_Click -->
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Name="btnEncrypt" Height="25" Margin="10" Content="EncryptAsync" Click="btnEncrypt_Click"/>
        <!-- CheckBox для режима шифрования (моментально или по нажатию на кнопку) -->
        <CheckBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Name="chkMomentalEncrypt" Margin="10" Content="Шифровать при вводе текста"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Код программы в файле MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Обработчик ввода текста. ВЫзывается каждый раз при изменении содержимого в TextBox
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private async void txtInput_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // моментальное шифрование текста по мере его ввода
            if(chkMomentalEncrypt.IsChecked != null && chkMomentalEncrypt.IsChecked.Value)
            {
                txtResult.Text = await EncryptAsync(txtInput.Text);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Обработчик нажатия на кнопку
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private async void btnEncrypt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            txtResult.Text = await EncryptAsync(txtInput.Text);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// функция шифрования или замены в асинхронном режиме
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">Значения для обработки</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        internal Task<string> EncryptAsync(string value)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(() =>
            {
                return value.Replace("A", "Z");
            });
        }
    }
}
```